# Grant remote access on domain computer to single user

Tags: domain-controller, user-management

We have a small network with a DC, webserver & user computers.

I need to grant remote access with admin privileges to the webserver for a consultant that we are currently working with but not sure how to do this...

Anyone know how to do this??

Thanks...

Comment: What do you mean "remote access"? Do you mean the ability to log on remotely (via RDP) or do you mean the ability to access resources on this computer remotely?

Comment: Infinitely more information is going to be needed to assist you with this.

Comment: Sorry - thought the above would be sufficient... permit RDP access and admin rights to a webserver that sits on a domain. I think I have now got it sorted but perhaps you could offer some advice as to whether or not this is the correct way or not? 

1: Added a Consultant user group to the DC, 
2: Added the consultant as a user and a member of the Consultant group, 
3: Locally; on the webserver, I added the Consultant group to the remote desktop users group and the administrators group.

Comment: That will work as well, plus it provides the ability to swap users in and out of the AD group without having to touch the server. Also, Remote Desktop Users is a subset of the full administrator rights. Therefore, it's not necessary to add the user/group to both. Adding them to the local administrators group alone is sufficient.

Comment: Cheers John - picked that up from your answer and made the appropriate changes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about RDP (Remote Desktop) access with full administrator privileges, all you need to do is add the user to the local administrators group. This can be done by running the following from a command prompt.

```
net localgroup administrators <username> /add
```

The username will need to be fully qualified (`<domain>\<username`>) if it's a domain account. Also, the command prompt will need to be run on the server in question by an existing user with local administrator privileges.

Please note that local administrator privileges allows the user to do pretty much anything to the server.

Comment: +1 This can also be done by looking at the local users and groups gui tool, but either way this is the correct mechanism to follow. By default local admin users should be able to use RDP, and local admins are obviously, er, local admins.